# Sql Server Schemas, one private area per person, but have read access to others

Tags: sql-server, database, schema

I have a requirement for a database that is effectively a "play" area for people creating stats data for themselves and shared with others.

I have a read only database full of core data. All users have read access.

I want a second "play" database where 'n' people can query the "core" database and create there own tables, Sp's etc.  I want these users to have a schema each. I want everything they create to be added to their schema by default unless they specify it explicitly (ie [dbo]) in the script. I want them all to be able to collaborate and be able to read data (and look at sp's) from other users schema but not add objects or execute sps' in the others users schema.

These users use 2014 management studio to run these queries.  They all authenticate using Integrated Security (windows).

Can this be done?

I tried setting default schema on a user but by default when they add a table it goes to [dbo] because the property grid in 2014MS defaults to [dbo] and you have to edit it.  If they just enter "create table Table1" I want it to go into their schema

I tried making the user the owner of the schema. I tried setting public to have select access to these user schemas. But something is not right!

I would have thought this was a common setup where developers get their own schema within a single database. Or, is it always the case that separate DB's are used to achieve this?  I am sure others would appreciate a short script that sets this up for a couple of users :)

SQL Server admin is not my main area, so any guidance would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

For a test user `User1`, you can create a schema `UserSchema1` and do the following

> I want a second "play" database where 'n' people can query the "core" database

you can make the user part of the `db_datareader` role like this

```
USE [CoreDatabase]
GO
exec sp_addrolemember db_datareader, 'User1'
```

> I want everything they create to be added to their schema by default

Create the schema and add appropriate permissions

```
USE [PlayDatabase]
GO
CREATE SCHEMA [UserSchema1] AUTHORIZATION dbo;
GO
GRANT ALTER, DELETE, EXECUTE, INSERT, REFERENCES, SELECT, UPDATE, VIEW DEFINITION ON SCHEMA::UserSchema1 TO User1;

GRANT CREATE TABLE, CREATE PROCEDURE, CREATE FUNCTION, CREATE VIEW TO User1;
```

Make the schema default for the user

```
ALTER USER [User1] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[UserSchema1]
```

For more info refer this thread

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21733/allow-user-to-do-anything-within-his-own-schema-but-not-create-or-drop-the-schem

> I want them all to be able to collaborate and be able to read data (and look at sp's) from other users schema but not add objects or execute sps' in the others users schema.

Allow user to view definition of other user's objects and do `SELECT's` on play database

```
USE [PlayDatabase]
GO
GRANT VIEW Definition TO [User1]
GO
exec sp_addrolemember db_datareader, 'User1'
```

Comment: Excellent, much appreciated, giving it a go now.